# Error with Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code here i recently cant start the code cause error with cannt convert undefined or null to object :

```
Utils.getCardsInSets((ERR, DATA) => {
    if (!ERR) {
        allCards = DATA;
        console.log("Card data loaded. [" + Object.keys(DATA).length + "]");
    } else {
        console.log("An error occurred while getting cards: " + ERR);
    }
});
```

Error that showed on console

```
console.log("Card data loaded. [" + Object.keys(DATA).length + "]");
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Utils.getCardsInSets (/root/test/index.js:37:52)
    at Request.request [as _callback] (/root/test/utils.js:41:13)
    at Request.self.callback (/root/test/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/test/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/test/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
```

Comment: i think your DATA value is null or undefined thats why its giving that error.

Comment: Ah can you help me how i can handle that so code just pass it through?

Comment: You can handle it like this `if (!ERR) { if(DATA){ allCards = DATA; console.log("Card data loaded. [" + Object.keys(DATA).length + "]"); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Utils.getCardsInSets` returning `undefined` or `null` `DATA`. In the above code you are not passing any query params to the method, check whether need to pass any params or not.

If what ever doing is correct, then method is returning `undefined/null` based on certain condition. Just check for `DATA` then go for its keys length.

```
Utils.getCardsInSets((ERR, DATA) => {
    if (!ERR) {
        allCards = DATA;
        var datalength = (!!DATA) ? Object.keys(DATA).length : 0;
        console.log("Card data loaded. [" + datalength  + "]");
    } else {
        console.log("An error occurred while getting cards: " + ERR);
    }
});
```